# Make elements swap sizes when sorting

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I am just wondering whether with jquery-ui sortable I can make elements not just swap places but also swap sizes during sorting. So this way if I have a grid with elements of different sizes, I will be able to sort the content, but all the grid borders will be kept in same places.